# Regular expression with case statement

Tags: regex, sh, case

I tried to check my variable value with case statement and regular expression in `sh` script like the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

test="test.1.testing"

case $test in
test.[5-9]+.testing) echo "value type 1";;
test.[1-4]+.testing) echo "value type 2";;
esac
```

This script doesn't work, have any solution with `sh` script (`not bash`)

I changed the symbol `"+"` by `"*"` and the script run succesfully, but I need to test with `"+"` (for 1 or more occurrence)

```
#!/bin/sh

test="test.1.testing"

case $test in
    test.[5-9]*.testing) echo "value type 1";;
    test.[1-4]*.testing) echo "value type 2";;
esac
```

Comment: "doesn't work", means no response / error prompted ?

Comment: no error, empty result

Comment: I think, the "+" symbol is treated as a simple character not a regex symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching in `case` is performed according to *Pathname Expansion*. Special symbols are `*`, `?`, `[…]`.

Symbol `+` is treated as simple character, not a quantifier for `[]`.

The same is true for `*`; here it's not a regex quantifier for `[]` but rather a separate pattern symbol. In your case, it matches zero characters which results in successful pattern match. You can check this by removing `*` from `case`.

Thus you should use the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

test="test.1.testing"

case $test in
    test.[5-9].testing) echo "value type 1";;
    test.[1-4].testing) echo "value type 2";;
esac
```

Comment: you're right, have you any solution to do it with case statement?

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI I edited my answer and added the working code. If you need to match `test.11.testing` too, then I'd suggest using a tool with more sophisticated regular expressions, for example `perl`, `grep`, `sed`. Additionally, if you allow two digits, then what case does `test.15.testing` fall in? If only the first digit is important, add `*` after `]` like you did. Yet such construct would also allow `.1a.` as well as `.15.`; so if you want to ensure there are only digits, you have to use another tool to check the value.